# popuppanel is called by clickhandler of hyperlink on another popuppanel

Tags: java, gwt, popuppanel

I have 2 gwt PopupPanel in one class. The second popup is expected to be shown when the user clicks the hyperlink on popuppanel1. How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Problem:
Click the hyperlink on popuppanel1 
- the popuppanel2 is not shown at all.

```
PopupPanel popuppanel1=new PopupPanel();
PopupPanel popuppanel2=new PopupPanel();

//popuppanel1 and popuppanel2 add their components

popuppanel1.getHyperlink().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            popuppanel2.center();
        }
});
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on `popuppanel2.center();` to see if that line of code is being reached?

Comment: Are those panels _modal_ (`popuppanelX.isModal();`)? Are you using _glass_ (`popuppanelX.isGlassEnabled();`)? Please, show more code how those panels are set up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it is about the history token of hyperlink. It is okay when I switch it to Button instead of hyperlink.